# Extract true part of a multi-condition

Tags: java, if-statement

```
if (p1true || p2true || p3true) {
    System.out.println("we have a winner");
    System.out.println( );
}
```

How to print only the `true` condition in this case?

Comment: Break your `if`s into three separate tests if you want to see which one is true.

Comment: Also note that `||` doesn't even evaluate all conditions if one is already `true`. Because the final result is already known. So, technically, it wouldn't even be possible to differentiate the case when multiple conditions are `true`. Technically, Java would only know the first `true` condition.

Comment: You can do this inside the if condition. System.out.println(p1true?"P1":(p2true?"P2":"P3"));

Comment: As per `we have a winner` statement, your code works perfectly. But when you need who is winner, in that case you have to go for multiple `if` statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that.. At least, not that way. You can add other if-statements to check which condition is true. Your code can look like this:

```
if(p1true){
    System.out.println("P1 wins!");
    System.out.println();
}

else if(p2true){
    System.out.println("P2 wins!");
    System.out.println();
}

else if(p3true){
    System.out.println("P3 wins!");
    System.out.println();
}
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (p1true || p2true || p3true) {
        System.out.println("we have a winner, The Winner is : " + ( p1true ? "P1" ? p2true ? "P2" : "P3" ) );
        System.out.println( );
    }
```

Or Multiple if conditions like @Taslim answered which is more readable than this, although it takes more lines of code.